# Merge statement issue with on clause SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following temp tables

```
CREATE TABLE #Test2ABCD 
( VenueID int NOT NULL
, VenueName nvarchar(max)
, VenueAdd nvarchar(max)
, VenueCity nvarchar(max)
, VenueState nvarchar(max)
, VenueCounty nvarchar(max)
, VenueZip nvarchar(max)
, VenuePhone nvarchar(max)
, VenueFax nvarchar(max)
, VenueContactName nvarchar(max)
, VenueContactEmail nvarchar(max)
, VenueContactPhone nvarchar(max)
, VenueWebsite nvarchar(max)
, VenueLat float
, VenueLong float
, VenueRating nvarchar(max)
, MapURL nvarchar(max)
, XMLResult xml);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE #SprocRes2ABCD 
(  RowID int identity(1,1) not null
, GPSLatitude float
, GPSLongitude float
, City nvarchar(max)
, State nvarchar(max)
, PostalCode nvarchar(max)
, Address nvarchar(max)
, County nvarchar(max)
, MapURL nvarchar(max)
, XMLResults xml);
```

When I try to execute the following merge statement

```
MERGE INTO #Test2ABCD t 
USING #SprocRes s ON (t.VenueID=s.RowID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET t.VenueCounty = s.County
           , t.VenueLat = s.GPSLatitude
           , t.VenueLong = s.GPSLongitude;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Invalid column name 'RowID'.

I know this has something to do with the "RowId" Column being an identity column but does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this... You call your table `#SprocResABCD`, but your statement uses `#SprocRes` - might it be that simple?

Comment: I can't see declaration of `#SprocRes` table you are using. Maybe it should be `#SprocRes2ABCD`?

Comment: Wow I think I need to give up.  Thank you for pointing out the horribly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems that my eyes have stopped functioning!  It was indeed a typo in the final line.  Thank you very much for the code review